# python mysql.connector returns none as function result

Tags: python, mysql, function, connector

I've got a function on MySQL server (Percona 5.x) and it works fine:

```
SET @id := 15037051;
SELECT get90DaysCount(@id) as get90DaysCount;
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8NMX.png]

But when I try to invoke this function from python using `mysql.connector`:

```
query = "SELECT get90DaysCount(15037051) as get90DaysCount";
self.cursor.execute(query)
records = self.cursor.fetchone()
print(records)
```

I get `None`:

```
((None,),)
```

All other values in complex query in which this function is beeing called are fine.

Tried to invoke other functions, and they work fine too. For example:

```
query = "SELECT getAverageMonthlyPayment(15037051) as p"
self.cursor.execute(query)
records = self.cursor.fetchone()
print(records)
```

Result:

```
(2795.1201171875,)
```

UPD. Ta-da! An here is a result of this query in console mysql client:

```
MySQL > SELECT get90DaysCount(15037051) as get90DaysCount;
+----------------+
| get90DaysCount |
+----------------+
| NULL           |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.098 sec)
```

Would be grateful for any ideas.

UPD2. Function code:

```
create function get90DaysCount(contract_id int) returns date
BEGIN
        DECLARE r DATE DEFAULT NULL;

        SELECT
            DATE_ADD(s.action_date, INTERVAL 88 DAY),
                INTO r
        FROM status_changes AS s
        WHERE
            s.c_id=@contract_id
        AND (
                SELECT COUNT(id) as count
                FROM status_changes AS s1
                WHERE
                    s1.c_id=@contract_id
                AND s1.status_new IN ('closed')
                AND datediff(s1.action_date, s.action_date) < 90
                AND datediff(s1.action_date, s.action_date) > 0
            ) = 0
        LIMIT 1;
        RETURN r;
    END;
```

UPD3:
May be this could help:

- Server version: 5.7.34-37-log Percona Server (GPL), Revision 6081c95
- mysql (local client) Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
- DataGrip 2022.3.1 (Build #DB-223.8214.6). Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.14 amd64
- Linux *** 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Where's the source of that function?

Comment: `here is a result of this query in console mysql client` Well, that shows `NULL` which converts to Python `None`. What's wrong?

Comment: The functions returns DATE type value (for this particular contract), not NULL (see screenshot from DataGrip). But it seems to me that there is something wrong with a client and based on its library python module.

Comment: Your "UPD" clearly shows `NULL`.

Comment: @aaron The problem that function returns value or null in different clients.